# Networking W7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, file-sharing

So we have a small office network setup, one Windows 7 computer and one Ubuntu 12.04 networked through an unmanaged switch and Virgin Router.

I have my Windows computer running a WAMP server for web development.

Everything was working fine until Windows crashed (whilst install Avast), since then, neither Ubuntu or Window can see each other... they can't even ping each other!

I have been through various forums, but to no avail.

1. I have tried disabling Ubuntus firewall: 'sudo service ufw stop'
2. I have tried disabling Windows Firewall both front end and through
   administration tools (because it doesn't seem to actually turn off!)
3. I have made sure the correct windows services are started according
   to this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5f8f9677-4a55-4e19-9843-b4c71aab93b1/network-discovery-keeps-turning-itself-back-off-?forum=winserverPN) (network disco keep turning off!):
4. I have tried system restore (which partially failed... I think).

I have disabled and re-enabled my adaptors and router and restarted both computers.

Now at a loss. It was working perfectly, anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Ed

EDIT

Reinstalled samba and restarted Ubuntu machine. Port forwarded port 80 through Win Firewall. All Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for getting back... Other devices pinged fine from W7 not from Ubuntu. We reinstalled samba and everything started working. Had to forward port 80 in W7 to get WAMP working after fighting with firewall. Just to clarify the problem was with Ubuntu not Win... the crash was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the two computers via Ethernet cable. On windows set an IP and netmask (say, 10.100.0.55 netmask 255.255.255.0). On linux type this - `ifconfig eth0 10.100.0.56 netmask 255.255.255.0 up` and ping them. If so, then you have a problem with your router.

On windows, try this:

- Start -> Run -> `netsh winsock reset`
- Start -> Run -> `devmgmt.msc` and remove your network card. Have the card's drivers at hand.
- Restart the computer.

Also: check your Windows and Ubuntu routing tables.